# Supressing warnings for a codeblock using gcc 4.1.2?

Tags: c++, boost, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have a section of code that uses a Boost library that results in a lot of these type of warning messages:

```
class x has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
```

Using g++ 4.1.2, how do I temporarily disable warnings for this codeblock then enable them again after it.

Everything I try (pragma gcc diagnostic, etc) seems to only be supported by a later version of g++.

How do I suppress just these warnings?

Comment: Fixing the warnings in your code is not an option? The condition (virtual functions but non-virtual destructor) usually points to a design error...

Comment: It's not in my code, it's in boost...

Comment: Out of interest, which Boost library is this? And which version?

Comment: It's in Boost logging. Non-virtual destructors don't always point to a design error (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm - guideline 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `-Wno-non-virtual-dtor`.

You can restrict this option to affect only certain files.
Can you move your "bad" code to separate c++ file? If so, turn this option only for that file.